# Draw a simple 2 line using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Can we easily draw a picture like below?
Where should I start from?

[image: e]

Comment: To simply answer your question: yes. Honestly, I am very sure that the [documentation of TikZ/PGF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) gives enough information on how to use TikZ to draw such a simple structure. Start with defining three `\node`s add `label`s to them and connect them with `\draw`s …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jasper is saying, this is very basic. This code may give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={fill=cyan,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt},
every label/.style={align=left,font=\small\sffamily}]
 \path (0,4) node[bullet,label={[anchor=south west]:{1\\ 12.20}}] (p1){}
 (4,4.4) node[bullet,label={[anchor=south west]:{3\\ 12.20}}] (p2){}
 (2.5,0) node[bullet,label={[anchor=south west]:{2\\ 9.80}}] (p3){};
 \draw[orange,thick] (p1.center) -- (p2.center) -- (p3.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would think that the following looks a tiny bit better.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={fill=cyan,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt},
every label/.style={align=left,font=\small\sffamily}]
 \path (0,4) node[bullet,label={[anchor=south]:{1\\ 12.20}}] (p1){}
 (4,4.4) node[bullet,label={[anchor=south west]:{3\\ 12.20}}] (p2){}
 (2.5,0) node[bullet,label={[anchor=north]:{2\\ 9.80}}] (p3){};
 \draw[orange,thick] (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If not, it illustrates a bit what the keys are for.

Comment: @aan No, this does not replace a figure environment. You can use `\begin{figure}[h!] \centering\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\caption{...}\label{fig:...}\end{figure}` but not in the `standalone` class, which does not support floats.

Comment: how can we draw a border line (like a box) in the original picture?

Comment: @aan Add `\draw([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.south west)
  rectangle ([xshift=1ex,yshift=1ex]current bounding box.north east);` just before `\end{tikzpicture}`. `1ex` is the grace distance, which you can adjust to your needs. Or use the `show background rectangle`, which requires the `backgrounds` library.

Comment: Thanks. Brillant!